# Can one prove divergence by showing a series has at most one solution for an=0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say I have any series, I would think it was enough to show that this series equals 0 at most once to prove it diverges. My logic is, 
For a series: 
$\sum a_n →∞$, and diverges, if $a_n≠0$ for $n→∞$ 
$\sum a_n →h∈R$, and converges, if $a_n=0$ for $n→∞$ 
Therefore if a series converges: 
$a_n=0$ for all $n>ϵ$ where ϵ is close to ∞ 
$n>ϵ$ for x values of n 
$x>1$ if $a_n=0$ for n→∞ 
$\therefore$ If a series $a_n$ has at most one real solution for $a_n=0$ it must diverge

Alternatively, if this is false, is it enough to show it has at most one solution for $a_n=x$ where x is very close to 0, and therefore diverges 
It this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reasoning is incorrect.  The issue is that there are series that converge with terms that are all non-zero.

A classical example is the geometric series.  Define $a_n = ( \frac{1}{2} )^n$ for $n \geq 0$.  It is clear that there are no solutions to $a_n = 0$, and yet the series converges! (in this case, $\sum a_n = 2$ !)

Moreover, what you have written has some poor intuitions resting behind it.  Your opening statements are both incorrect, for example.  If for all $n$, $a_n \neq 0$, then we do not get that the series diverges.  In fact, we can only say that a partial converse to this statement is correct.  It is true that IF a series diverges, then $a_n \neq 0$ for infinitely many $n$.  A counterexample to your statement is the sequence $a_n = 1$ if $n$ is even, and $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is odd.  Note that $\sum a_n \rightarrow \infty$, yet it also has infinitely many terms that are $0$.

Your second statement is close to correct, but it belies some poor intuitions on how limits work.  The correct statement is that IF a series $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n = 0$.  This is very different than $a_n =0$ since, as in the geometric series example, a series can converge without any of the terms being $0$ on their own.

As a final thought, it is best not to use the phrase "where $\epsilon$ is close to $\infty$".  One immediate question that comes to mind if I see this phrase while grading a homework assignment is "well how close to $\infty$ is $\epsilon$?".  The short answer is that since $\infty$ isn't a number, it's not good to think of things being "close" to it in any meaningful way, and in fact, the ONLY way to "approach" infinity is via a limit.  So just use the limit notation, trust me, it won't bite.

Answer (score 2):

No this reasoning is not correct. The terms of the geometric sequence $a_n = \dfrac{1}{2^n}$ are never equal to zero but $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ converges to $1$.

Also, all the terms of this geometric series are distinct. So, for any $x$ there is at most one solution $n$ to $a_n = x$. Thus, your second line of reasoning is also incorrect.